# Detail of all transactions on a specific row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I've a `User` table and It's data can be added/ updated from a `User Screen.` I want `detail of all transactions on any row`.

For example, I have data in table like this

> Name - Age -  Salary
>
> John    -  25 - $10
>
> Jazy    -  23 - $10

Then some user update john's Age like this

> Name - Age -  Salary
>
> John    -  **20** - $10
>
> Jazy    -  23 - $15

and then Update its Salary like this

> Name - Age -  Salary
>
> John    -  20 - **$20**
>
> Jazy    -  23 - $15

I want a query to get `all transactions on John's records` like this

> John    -  25 - $10
>
> John    -  20 - $10
>
> John    -  20 - $20

Is there any way to get data like this??

Comment: It sounds like you want something like Change Data Capture. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Forgot that [Change data capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is already in 2008, you could use it to capture the data, or create your own log/history table using triggers or something similar.

If you were in SQL Server 2016, then you could use [temporal tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)

Comment: Change data capture is available in 2008

Comment: @TomV Oh yes, of course that's available in 2008

Comment: I checked this and CDC is enabled for my database and table. But I'm still unable to capture row detail. Do I still need custom query to get all changes??

Comment: Look into the CDC functions.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627(v=sql.100).aspx